# "Auto Update: Security" apk in downloads section

Tags: applications, security

I found an apk called "Auto Update: Security" in the downloads folder of my phone.
I wasn't able to access its details as every time I tried to do so the package installer would start, with the warning that downloading apks from an external source is unsafe. I ended up deleting the apk as I wasn't able to confirm its origin

Is this a normal update for the Security app? If so, then why do I get the warning?
I don't recall having any system app updates ever being pushed through the downloads section since it has a separate section called "System app updates".

The device in question is a POCO M3 and is running on MIUI.

Comment: Seems very uncommon, though without knowing what it is actually (since there's no info about this APK on the internet), it's hard to comment further. Perhaps next time you can [upload it to VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to get some basic information about the app.

Comment: Android system update are usually not stored in the Downloads folder and they don't come as an APK. The file may be downloaded by an app that is not present in Google Play Store or it is malware that tries to trick you to install it. I would recommend to delete it. If the update comes from an app the app should inform and ask you before downloading an update.

Comment: @AndrewT. I checked the System app updates section and it shows a prompt to update the Security app, so it's possible that I may have uninstalled the update. Even then, it seems pretty sketchy to me. I ran the phone through the Bitdefender app as well as Malwarebytes and nothing came up, but I doubt whether they ever detect anything.

Comment: @Robert I deleted the app and cleared the browser data as well. Is this enough?

Comment: If you have not installed the APK file this should be enough.

Comment: https://blog.zimperium.com/new-advanced-android-malware-posing-as-system-update/
This is the closest I could find and frankly speaking, it's pretty terrifying.